# Need image to maintain position regardless of screen size

Tags: java, html, css, image

I am trying to add a "proceed to cart" button on my website, 
and I can manage to have the button with this code, the only issue is that
that button moves around the page depending on the screen size. My button is just and image with a link attached.

Can anyone tell me what I would add or modify to this code so that the image or button maintains its position regardless of screen size?

```
<p><a href="https://www.google.com/"><img alt="" src="image.png" style="position: relative; top: 340px; left: 415px; width: 224px; height: 46px;" /></a></p>
```

I understand that the "position; relative" can be changed to "sticky" or "absolute" and a few more however I feel like I'm missing something else beyond that.

Also understand that "google.com" and "image.png" are in place of actual links and images but I just condensed it for the sake of the code.

Thank you,

Nicole

Comment: change display:relative to display:fixed https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: @KatyH. I think you mean position: fixed, not display. :)

Comment: correction - position:fixed. thanks!